# SQL Server Need Some Help Joins , please

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables A, B, C. There is a relationship between tables A and C while there is a relationship between tables B and C . There is no relationship between A and B.

What I would really like to do is get a list of all the records from B when there are records in C related to B given a value from A .

Please let me know, if this is not clear enough 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can right query something like this...

```
SELECT B.* FROM B
INNER JOIN C ON C.aa = B.aa
INNER JOIN A ON A.bb = C.bb
WHERE A.cc = @yourvalue
```

@yourvalue is your value on which bases you need to select the value from B table. if you need match mutliple values from A then you need to change bit of query some thing like this...

```
WHERE A.cc IN (@val1,@val2,@val3....,@valNth)
```

In this query we have used INNER JOIN so it will gives only those records which are common on both the tables LIKE if you only join B with C then it will give the records which are common in B and C and then you join A with C then it will give those records which are common in A and C.

So suppose in B there is records something like 1,2,3 and in C there is 2,3,4,5 and in A there is 1,3,4,5

so the output of above query (without applying WHERE cause) is 1,3 only because this is common in all three table A,B,C.

you can got more information for joins in sqlserver by refering this links..

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/W1aI140312-Different-Types-of-SQL-Joins.html

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/different-types-of-joins-in-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple math dictates if there is a relationship between A and C, and a relationship between B and C, there *is*, albeit by association, a relationship between A and B (through C).

Thus you will need to join all three together, going from A, through C, to B:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM A
JOIN C ON A.x = C.x
JOIN B ON B.y = C.y
WHERE A.z = @z
```

Comment: that is true.. but I am not getting any records for B . I am expecting some values to come up since I am only searching for values of B that dont have any corresponding values in C given the above statement.

Comment: If you have corresponding records exist in all three tables then and only then you got the record selected, because you have mention that "What I would really like to do is get a list of all the records from B when there are records in C related to B given a value from A . "